# Can averaged limits of sequences be realized as limits of sequences?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

Let a summation method take a sequence $(x_n)$ to a net $(y_\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ runs over a partially ordered set, $y_\alpha=\sum c_{\alpha,n}x_n$ ($c_{\alpha,n}\geq 0$, $\sum_n c_{\alpha,n}=1$ for every $\alpha$ and $c_{\alpha,n}\to 0$ in $\alpha$ for every $n$). *Is it possible to find a sequence* $(\alpha_m)$ *of indices such that convergence of* $(y_\alpha)$ *imply convergence of* $(y_{\alpha_m})$?

Take the Abel summation method as an example: the set of indices is $(0, 1)$, and convergence of the Abel means $(y_r)$ yields that for $(y_{r_m})$, where $(r_m)$ is an arbitrary sequence tending to 1.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is there a paper or a book where summability is studied in this generality (using directed sets and nets)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the same sequence $(\alpha_m)$ for each sequence from the convergence field of your summation method.

I'll try to show that [ultralimit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit) can be realized as a summability method in the way you described.

Let $\mathcal F$ be any free ultrafilter. Let us define
$$D=\{(A,n); n\in A, A\in\mathcal F\}$$
and $$(A,n)\le (B,m) \Leftrightarrow A\supseteq B.$$
Then $(D,\le)$ is a directed set. For $\alpha=(A,n)\in D$ we define
$$c_{\alpha,k}=
\begin{cases}
1;&k=n,\\\\
0;&k\ne n.
\end{cases}$$
which means that $y_\alpha=x_n$.

Now $y_\alpha$ converges to $L$ if and only if $L$ is the $\mathcal F$-limit of the sequence $(x_n)$. (This is very similar to the usual correspondence between filters and nets in topological spaces, see e.g. Proposition 6.2. [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf).) This implies that every bounded sequence is summable.

However, if we choose any sequence $\alpha_m=(A_m,n_m)$ then the convergence of $(x_{\alpha_m})$ is in fact the convergence of $(x_{n_m})$. For any given sequence $(n_m)$ it is easy to exhibit an example of a bounded sequence $x$ such that $(x_{n_m})$ is not convergent.

---

The above example shows that your claim is not true for arbitrary directed sets. However, if you work with a directed set which contains a [cofinal subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_%28mathematics%29) of order type $(\mathbb N,\le)$, then it is obviously true. (Which is the case in the example you suggested.) I suspect that it should work even for directed sets having any countable cofinal subset. There is a post at math.stackexchange related to the nets of this type: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41634/ordered-sets-that-are-like-sequences/